# How to approach the dataset with a continuous and discrete label?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, supervised-learning

Let's say you're predicting the amount of money to bet in a poker game. Based on the game situation, you might decide to fold. In that case, the amount of money to bet is zero. If you decide to call or raise, the amount of money to bet is non-zero.

I have tried to apply a linear regression model to this problem, but I got non-zero prediction for all input. So right now, I'm thinking of doing classification on the whole dataset first to predict if the output is zero or non-zero, then do a simple regression to predict an amount for the non-zero ones. In a sense, the output is both discrete and continuous.

Is this a right approach to do?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of first classifying whether to fold, to call or to raise (btw you could consider 3 labels here) is reasonable, then you could have a regression task for the amount to bet/raise if this move is predicted.

Another option is to restrict the range of predicted values: if the linear regression predicts a value lower or equal X, consider it equal to zero. Anyway this is necessary if only to take care of the rules of the game: usually the bet must be at least equal to the big blind, so if the linear regression gives an amount lower than that it has to be rounded up or down.

Side note: this can be a fun ML project, but I wouldn't use this kind of algorithm with any real money game for at least two reasons:

1. afaik bots are illegal with most poker sites
2. linear regression is very basic, it's very unlikely that the algorithm will play optimally
3. an experienced opponent will very easily notice the pattern and outplay the algorithm
4. Given the diversity of the situations, you need a massive amount of poker hands to train the model in order to obtain anything minimally reliable.